# jQuery hover event for input textbox is not working

Tags: jquery, css, hover, jquery-events

I have a web page with html and jQuery code as below. I have subscribed to hover event of an input text box with id of `firstname`, but it never fires on hovering over the text box. I have placed this event code in document ready event.

Demo for this question is at this URL: [demo sample](http://js.do/sun21170/77269)

**Question**: What is wrong in the jQuery code that I have below for subscribing to the hover event? My goal is to apply the `highlight` class whenever the text box is hovered over.

**Html code**

```
<style>
   .highlight {
   background-color: yellow;
   border: 1px red solid;
   }
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
   <tr class='class1'>
      <td>
         <!--some content here-->
         I am a td element
      </td>
      <td>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  First Name 
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type='text' id='firstname'>  
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  Last Name 
               </td>
               <td>
                  <input type='text' id='lastname'>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var firstName = $('#firstname');
    firstName.on('hover', function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('highlight') === false) {
            $(this).addClass('highlight');
        } 
    });
});
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

Based on the answers, I have updated the demo sample. You can see the modified sample at this URL: [modified demo sample that is working](http://js.do/sun21170/77272).

In this modified sample, I have just followed the approach suggested by DinoMyte, which is to use the following format when dealing with hover effect/event in jquery: `jQueryObject.hover(on function when hovering starts, off function when hovering out)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`hover` event can be binded, not delegated. You need to replace

```
firstName.on('hover', function() {
```

with this :

```
firstName.hover(function() {
```

Working : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/jmt4bmtm/

If you wish to delegate that event, you need to use alternate approach with `mouseover`.

UPDATE : if you wish to trigger on-off effect on hover, you can do the following :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       var firstName = $('#firstname');
       firstName.hover(function() 
       {
         if($(this).hasClass('highlight') === false) 
         $(this).addClass('highlight');
       }, 
       function() 
       {
         $(this).removeClass('highlight');
      }
   );
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/jmt4bmtm/1/

If delegation is really important for your solution, you can use the following approach using `mouse` events.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
       var firstName = $('#firstname');
       firstName.on("mouseover",function() 
       {
         if($(this).hasClass('highlight') === false) 
         $(this).addClass('highlight');
       }).on("mouseleave",function()
       {
         $(this).removeClass('highlight');
       });
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/jmt4bmtm/3/

Comment: So I cannot use jQuery on and off with hover event? Ok. Let me try your suggestion.

Comment: Yes it works. Is there an equivalent of jQuery off that I can use with your approach?

Comment: giving the input a border by default keeps it from jumping around on the page when adding the highlight class.  https://jsfiddle.net/jmt4bmtm/4/

Comment: @Sunil There is no `hover` event. The `hover` function is a shortcut for binding the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

Comment: Get it. So we can pass the first function for `on` effect and second function  for `off` effect when using this approach for subscribing to events in jquery?

Comment: @Barmar. You mean `mouseenter`  event is the exact same as `hover`?

Comment: No. `hover` is for binding **two** functions, one when start hovering, another when you stop.

Comment: @Barmar, Got it. Didn't know that fact. Thanks. That is why the event subscribing does not work with `hover` since its not really an event.

Comment: If you want to use `.off`, do `.off("mouseenter mouseleave")`

Comment: And for the `on` part on.("mouseenter mouseleave"). Great. I have learnt a lot from you guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could bind the `hover` event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var firstName = $('#firstname');
  firstName.hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
  }, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/av38Lvqs/